# Ошибка при построении AJAX запроса в Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Возникает ошибка при формировании ответа от файла-обработчика:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in  functions.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in functions.php on line 15

Код следующий (на фронте):

```
 jQuery(function() {
  var $mainBox = jQuery('.team-about');
  jQuery('.team-item a').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkTeamMember = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    ajaxTeam(linkTeamMember);
  });
  function ajaxTeam(linkTeamMember){
    $mainBox.animate({opacity: 0.5}, 300);
    jQuery.post(
        "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/functions.php",
        {
            action: 'get_team',
            link: linkTeamMember
        },
        function (response){
            $mainBox
                .html(response)
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        });
    }
});
```

На бэке (function.php):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_team', 'show_member_team' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_team', 'show_member_team' );

function show_member_team(){

    $link = !empty($_POST['link']) ? esc_attr($_POST['link']) : false;
    $slug = $link ? wp_basename($link) : false;
    $team = get_post($slug);
    if(!$team){
        die('Член команды не найден');
    }

    return query_posts($team);
}
```

Подскажите чем может быть вызвана данная ошибка? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Потому что нельзя напрямую вызывать functions.php. Инициализировать ядро WordPress кто за вас будет? Святой дух? Почитайте, как надо создавать ajax в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign тогда как поступить?

Comment: Иными словами, add_action не определена, потому что это функция ядра. А ядро вы не подключили.

Comment: Я дал ссылку на очень толковое описание на русском, как надо создавать ajax в WP

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо за подсказку, разобрался)